# Redefine Awesome stacked icons as one icon with CSS rules only

Tags: css, font-awesome

FontAwesome 3.2.1

I want to use Awesome stacked icons (font icons that placed one upon the other) using only CSS. Is it possible to define concrete icons some special CSS rule ?

Now stacked icons are used so, so icon-check-empty will be shown over icon-twitter.

```
<span class="icon-stack">
  <i class="icon-check-empty icon-stack-base"></i>
  <i class="icon-twitter"></i>
</span>
```

I want to define CSS rules (myclass) so that I can use it in one span instead.

```
my.css
  icon-twitter-on-icon-check-empty {  } 
  .....


my.html
  <span class="icon-twitter-on-icon-check-empty" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, certainly.

You should create a generic class for establishing the spacing for your icons and the background image to be added, then a chained or complementary class for determining the sprite's background position.

Edit: I didn't realize you wanted to actually display several icons on top of one another. That's a very different matter. You would want to use positioning to do that.

Comment: font awesome doesn't use sprites, it uses font instead.

Comment: @JohnN - then you should be able to do it by targetting the span's :before pseudo-element and setting the font to use for the images (in the general rule) and the character to append to content (in the specific rule).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am new to css. Could you give a link  or explanation to your idea, so that I can better imagine what you are talking about.

Comment: The stacked icons are two icons that placed one upon the other. So your proposal will be to `<span class="icon icon-printer icon-tratata">Print this page</span>` ? Does it sufficient to use it that way or do I need position:absolute css rule?

Comment: @JohnN - no, I didn't realize you wanted to actually place multiple icons on the same element. I thought you wanted the ability to chain classes rather than rely on an ancestor class.

Answer (score 0):

Through CSS only, this has the Face Time icon in the before of the CSS and the pause on top in red in the after.  I'm using this code to override a web theme, which is why there is a background-image:none.

So in your css:

```
.videoIcon {
    background-image:none!important;
    position:relative;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size:small;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
    .videoIcon:before {
    content: "\f03d";
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
    .videoIcon:after{
    content:"\f04c";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom:0;
    color:red;
    font-size:smaller;
}
```